# Can't use both image links with z-index

Tags: html, css

I want to use my logo and banner image links. I am trying to position  the logo layered on the top of my  banner with z-index. But I cant seem to use the link for my banner.

Here is my code:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span10 ">
           <a href="/"><img src="../assets/img/sirtcantalilar-logo.png" class="toplogo" alt="sirtcantalilar-logo" /></a>
            <a href="http://www.turkishairlines.com/tr-tr/wingoya-katil" target="_blank">
            <img src="../assets/img/banner-yeni.jpeg" class="topbanner" alt="wingo-katil" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

style.css

```
img.topbanner
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index:-1;

}

img.toplogo {
    z-index: 0;
    position:relative;
    padding-top:10px;
}
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Try giving `z-index: 1` to banner, and `z-index: 2` to logo. Don't use negative values.

Comment: Hey it did the solution.

Comment: So, I'll post it as an answer, then you can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try giving `z-index: 1` to banner, and `z-index: 2` to logo. Don't use negative values.

```
img.topbanner {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index: 1;
}

img.toplogo {
    z-index: 2;
    position:relative;
    padding-top:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this MDN article, [Stacking Without z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FUnderstanding_z-index%2FStacking_without_z-index), and then check out how adding z-index into the mix does and does not change things: [Adding z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FUnderstanding_z-index%2FAdding_z-index).

The gist of it is that the z-index of absolutely position elements takes precedence over that of relatively positioned elements. One option is to make your `.toplogo` image absolutely positioned, so that it and the banner are both being rendered in the same z-index range:

```
img.topbanner {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index:1;
}
img.toplogo {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer .. only positioning toplogo to absolute harms view .. I will leave it as relative.

Comment: Making a `relative` element to `absolute` one, will change the result in view. The problem was in negative `z-index`.